# Fold: highlight folded text only

Tags: highlight, folding

[image]

I expected the folded text highlighted as below picture (ignore `red` rectangle):
[image]

Like the above picture, I'd like to have something to recognize that `red` region of a fold and highlight it only, do not have `ctermbg` apply to the region of the redundant space.

This question is kind of general, I don't have much experience so I try to explain from the user's perspective, I'd like to have that `red` region highlighted only that is a folded block of text.

Comment: can you show us picture as it is and another one as it should be?

Comment: @MaximKim: I've just update the picture of expected folded text. Don't count the `red` rectangle.

Comment: Ok, it is clear now. I don't think it is possible though.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible.

The folded text always uses the highlighting group [Folded](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#hl-Folded) for the complete screen line.

However, you can of course change the highlighting group so that it doesn't stand out so much.

For example remove the background attribute of the Folded group to make only the text standout (or you could use a background attribute that doesn't have such a big contrast to the Normal highlighting group:

```
hi Folded ctermfg=102 guifg=#878787 guibg=NONE ctermbg=NONE
```

Note, that this might make it hard to realize that this is actually folded text as can be seen here:[image]

Comment: Is there a way to check if it's folded or not and then `matchgroup` against it and use custom highlight? Remove `ctermbg` is not the way because I need it highlighted.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you like to do

Comment: I only need remove `ctermbg` on redundant spaces but keep on the text.

Comment: @TuyenPham as I said at the beginning of my answer, that is not possible

Comment: Is there a way of vim to recognize e.g: if/then condition to check if a line is a fold or not? Then logically we can match that line and do our task to exclude spaces.

Comment: there are various functions to be used for checking if a line is folded or not, see `:h function-list`. However, that won't let you do what you want. The highlighting group is global, once you change it, it will take effect for all windows, buffers and all characters in each fold